connected to samba share on nas but after restarting arch desktop problems occur
I recently swapped from Windows 10 to Arch Linux.
I connected to a Samba share on NAS but after restarting Arch desktop, the Nautilus file manager says "folder is empty".
I connected to it via a symlink so I can acces all my files.

(1) Did the NAS give you your files when you used a windows client? (2) Is this symlink you mention present on your client or on the NAS? (3) If it's on the client can you see your files if you go to the true place in the client filesystem where it has mounted the NAS network share? Please update your question incorporating detail addressing these points
